Web API Token Based Authentication Error : Authorization has been denied for this request
I'm developing an ASP.NET Web API. It runs smoothly without authentication, but when I try to access the API in Postman with username and password, I always get an error:

Authorization has been denied for this request

UserController code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WEBAPITOKENAUTHENTICATION.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/data/forall")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Now server time is: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/data/authenticate")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetForAuthenticate()
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            return Ok("Hello " + identity.Name);
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/data/authorize")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetForAdmin()
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            var roles = identity.Claims
                .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                .Select(c => c.Value);

            return Ok("Hello " + identity.Name + " Role: " + string.Join(",", roles.ToList()));
        }
    }
}

I created 3 classes in my project:

ApiAuthorizationServerProvider
ApiAuthorizeAttribute
AuthenticationStartup

ApiAuthorizationServerProvider code:
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace WEBAPITOKENAUTHENTICATION
{
    public class ApiAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            if (context.UserName == "admin" && context.Password == "admin")
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "admin"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Hi Admin"));
                context.Validated(identity);
            }
            else if (context.UserName == "user" && context.Password == "user")
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Hi User"));
                context.Validated(identity);
            }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password are incorrect");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

ApiAuthorizeAttribute code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WEBAPITOKENAUTHENTICATION
{
    public class ApiAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }
        }
    }
}

AuthenticationStartup code:
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WEBAPITOKENAUTHENTICATION.AuthenticationStartup))]

namespace WEBAPITOKENAUTHENTICATION
{
    public class AuthenticationStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var myProvider = new ApiAuthorizationServerProvider();

            var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = myProvider
            };

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        }
    }
}

Please help me solve the issue


When i remove authentication it works but when i apply authorize on user and admin its not works.

In postman  add Auth Type as Bearer Token under Authorization menu

Still same issue {
"Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}

The screen capture doesn't show http method and the url. Please add them to your question. If you put a breakpoint in GetForAdmin() can you confirm user has admin role?

For the record, based on that code it seems you're following this tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/web-ap/

If you put a breakpoint inside GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method, does it break? It may be your custom provider.
